# Ошибка при создании bitmap из файла

Tags: java, android

При создании bitmap из файла если файл изображения выходит ошибка

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 35712588 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 29MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
```

Есть хороший метод который помогает избежать проблема при изменении размера, но вот когда я создаю bitmap из файла я не знаю какой у него размер высоты и ширины, так что данный метод я использовать не могу.

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f,int WIDTH,int HIGHT){
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_WIDTH= WIDTH;
        final int REQUIRED_HIGHT= HIGHT;
        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale=1;
        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_WIDTH && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_HIGHT)
            scale*=2;

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

И если скачиваю файл из интернета, и передаю InputStream  в метод, изображение сохраняется пустым.

```
public static Bitmap decodeFileInputStream(InputStream  f,int WIDTH,int HIGHT){
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(f, null, o);

        //The new size we want to scale to

         int REQUIRED_WIDTH= WIDTH;
         int REQUIRED_HIGHT= HIGHT;
        Log.e(tag, bitmap.getHeight() + "");
        if(WIDTH == 0){
            REQUIRED_WIDTH = bitmap.getWidth()/2;
            REQUIRED_HIGHT = bitmap.getHeight()/2;
        }
        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale=1;
        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_WIDTH && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_HIGHT)
            scale*=2;

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(f, null, o2);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Уточните, у вас вопрос "почему падает ошибка?" или "как узнать размер битмапа?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему не можете знать размер? Ваш же пример:

```
 BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
```

Считывает только размеры без полного декодирвания.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, при скачивании из интернета у меня есть только inputSrtream с ним я хочу создать файл но файл остается пустым

Comment: Так о чем тогда это вопрос? О том что не можете узнать размер фаила о том что не хватает памяти при декодировании или то что не можете работать со скаченным фаилом? Это 3 разных вопроса и желательно оформить их так а не валить все  в кучу.

Comment: Да вы правы, не могу узнать размер изображения, его разрешение, когда я делаю как вы написали потом 
    Bitmap  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);  и bitmap.getHeight(); у меня выходит ошибка NullPointerException

Comment: Смотри стрим это как труба из которой вытекают байты. Ты уже взял часть байтиков когда пытался получить размер, потом из остатков пытаешься декодировать изображение. Обычно у stream есть reset() который вернет его состояние обратно, но оно может и отсутвовать в твоей конкретной реализации. 

Потому надежнее сначала будет сохранить его в временный фаил и работать уже с ним.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317035/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-virtual-file

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2); у меня же здесь используется все тот же файл из того же файла который на флешке я создаю тот же стрим, в итоге я не использую остаток стрима, но ведь даже при первом декодировании где мне нужно узнать размеры изображения у меня выдает nullPointerException,

Comment: BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);
REQUIRED_WIDTH = bitmap.getWidth()/2;
Ошибка выходит NullPointerException